# can FindFirstFile() be used to move a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, win32-process

Can FindFirstFile() be used to move or copy a file from one directory to another? Since it returns a handle, can this handle be used to do it?

Comment: A handle is just a special pointer. It doesn't matter how you get one. Why the question? Have you encountered a problem?

Comment: Haven't encountered a problem as such, this method just hit me when I was looking for ways to copy a file from one folder to another... Maybe my concept about handles is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's even not a kernel handle. This handle may **only** be passed to `FindNextFile` and `FindClose`.

P.S. You don't expect a handle returned by `CreateEvent` to be able to copy a file...

Answer (score 2):

The handle it returns is only useful to allow you to call FindNextFile().  Quite handy, lets you pass a wildcard ("*.*" for example) to iterate all the files that match.  Don't forget to call FindClose().

The real nugget is the WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName value it returns.  That's the one you need to call MoveFile() to actually move the file.

Comment: I didn't understand the real nugget line.. What are you suggesting? I tried using MoveFile(), but it didn't work. Also the path of the 2 files passed to MoveFile() is too damn long and I think that could be a problem..

Comment: @digvijay: if `MoveFile()` did not work for you, then you likely did not use it correctly. Note that `cFileName` returns just the filename, not a full path. It is relative to the folder being searched. Make sure you are passing full paths to `MoveFile()`. If it still does not work, then show your code here.

Answer (score 1):

The [MoveFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function just takes in 2 parameters (from file name, to file name) so you wouldn't need to use FindFirstFile to move a file.  The [CopyFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is similar.

Answer (score 1):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

See the quote:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a search handle used in
>   a subsequent call to FindNextFile or FindClose, and the lpFindFileData
>   parameter contains information about the first file or directory
>   found.

The return value is a search handle, not a file handle. From this, it would seem that you can not.

Answer (score 1):

`FindFirstFile` returns *search handle* (not *file handle*) and its purpose is only for file search. Since you're already passing file name (and path) as an argument to `FindFirstFile`, why not just passing it to `MoveFile/MoveFileEx`. You don't even need to call `FindFirstFile`, `MoveFile` would fail if file doesn't exist.